# Android: Custom popup menu that changes according to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, popupmenu

I need to do a popup menu that changes his options according to the tab (fragment) the user is in, and refresh the RecyclerView after the user changes something, like the classification. I have tried to do specific popups to each fragment, but I still learn how to handle menus, how do I need to create these different popups for each one, I wanted to understand this before proceeding with the menus of each fragment.

Something like the image ([example popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duvQJ.png)).

Comment: What have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: will update the question with that, thanks